# Не получается обновить pip в python

Tags: python, pip

Пытаюсь поставить stable diffusion. Все скачано, при запуске просит обновить pip:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.0.1

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 39, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 378, in prepare_environment
    run(f'"{python}" -m {torch_command}', "Installing torch and torchvision", "Couldn't install torch", live=True)
  File "E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 116, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.
Command: "E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
Error code: 1
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Если делать все четко по инструкции, как в данном сообщении, а именно попробовать обновить
pip через python.exe то получается следующее:

```
    -m pip install --upgrade pip
       ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Поползав по интернету понял, что нужно вводить через командную строку windows. Обновил до последней версии успешно, запускаю... Опять то же самое. Пытался перекидывать папку Scripts из диска C, где лежит основной Python, но безрезультатно. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Проблема вообще не с версией pip, а с тем что нет версии torch под вашу комбинацию операционной системы, битности и версии интерпретатора Python. Возможно на Python 3.12 пытаетесь установить. Если это так, то пробуйте установить на Python 3.11

Comment: Обновление `pip` - это не требование, а рекомендация, типа предупреждения. Оно вашу проблему не решит, разбирайтесь с `torch`. Внимательно прочитайте требования на операционку и прочее для установки `stable diffusion` и постарайтесь им следовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если делать все четко по инструкции, ...

То нужно полностью скопировать команду в командную строку, от начала до конца: `E:\AI1\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Тогда удастся обновить `pip`.

Но это, скорее всего, не поможет решить вашу проблему с установкой `torch`. Как уже предположили в комментариях, возможно, нужно установить *python* другой версии.

Comment: Перешел на 3.11 как и советовали, удалил 3.12, проблема решилась (только нужно было переименовать папку Python311 в Python312, потому что без этого оно не хотело работать), все работает, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло это: сначала из папки `stable-diffusion-webui-directml` в *cmd* ввел:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

потом удалил содержимое папки `stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv`

запустил `webui.bat` и ждал.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае как раз таки помогло обновления Pip (т.к. все остальное совпадало)
Просто как и писали выше, в первую очередь необходимо соответствие версий ПО (про питон в частности)

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте так:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```